# Problem on clicking anywhere in the HTML page

Tags: html, css

```html
<head>
    <title>Learn Coding Online | Treehouse</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

I created a webpage using HTML and CSS. Whenever I click anywhere in the page all the elements go to random positions and when I release the click they become normal again. I have attached the snippet and it looks completely fine. For seeing the problem I am providing the website link-https://whitiger26.github.io/try2/

Can someone please point out the reason behind this.

Thanks in advance.

P.S- I am new here so please ignore mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Removing the active part as told solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.subm ul li a:hover, .subm ul li a:active{ /* This line is changed */
    padding-left: 85.6px;
    padding-right: 85.6px;
    padding-bottom: 27px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #387bab;
    color: #387BAB;
}
```

`.subm ul li a:hover, :active` it basically select two elements
`.subm ul li a:hover` and `*:active` and due to this it selects all the elements in that page on click and apply that CSS code on them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out your issue.

In your "stylesheet.css" you have this code:

```
.subm ul li a:hover,:active{
    padding-left: 85.6px;
    padding-right: 85.6px;
    padding-bottom: 27px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #387bab;
    color: #387BAB;
}
```

You need to remove `, :active` because in css the way you have it, that's calling for literally anything and everything when "active" to by styled like that. Which is why your clicking everything problem changes everything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the same style from hover and active.

```
.input:active{
    border: 2px solid rgb(136, 135, 135);
}
.subm ul li a{
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
.subm ul li a{
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
.subm ul li a:hover, .subm ul li a:active{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #387bab;
    color: #387BAB;
}
```